# Segmentation fault (core dumped) when using fscanf in C, call-by-reference used

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

Im trying to write a simple program that reads a file and prints each line of the file. Each line will contain a name and their age, for example:

```
Jenny 16
Amy 24
```

I'm getting Segmentation fault (core dumped) and I'm not sure what is causing this problem since I have used call-by-reference for the integer value in the fscanf already. Will greatly appreciate any input
*sorry, i should have specified this before but the input file name is just file1 so it shouldn't be longer than the buffer

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char filename[10];
    scanf("%s",filename);
    FILE *file;
    char name[20];
    int num;
    file = fopen("filename", "r");
    while
    ((fscanf(file, "%s %d\n", name, &num)) != EOF) {
    printf("%s %d\n", name, num);
    }
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check the return value of `fopen`.  As it stands you will segfault if the file can't be opened.

Answer (score 2):

Simple error - `"filename"` is string literal, so `fopen("filename", "r");` will try to open file that does not exist. Change it to `fopen(filename, "r");` and it should work. Note, that reading from fscanf is unsafe - if the name is longer than 19 characters, the program can act in unpredictable way; fopen can overwrite other data in the program, null terminating character could be omitted, or program might execute just fine in many examples, and give weird result in others - it is called "undefined behaviour". Nevertheless for simple learning purpose this approach is enough - just keep in mind, that it can crash from time to time.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was going crazy wondering why the fscanf wasn't working...

Answer (score 0):

You need to limit the scanf so it doesn't read anything longer of your buffer. Probably the segmentation fault is because you are reading a name or a filename with more characters than your buffer's sizes. (to be sure, you should post your input data).

You should use scanf family of functions like this:

```
scanf("%9s",filename);
```

Notice I limit the size to 9 (because your buffer is 10 chars length) to leave room for scanf to put a \x00 to terminate the string.

Answer (score 0):

This is a circumstance where reading with `fscanf()` his horribly fragile. How would it handle:

```
Jenny 16
Minnie Mouse        92
```

or what if a space was missing?

```
Jenny16
Minnie Mouse92
```

Would `fscanf()` still work?

The key is to handle input in a *line-oriented* manner with `fgets()` (or POSIX `getline()`) to read the entire line into a buffer (character array) and then parse the values you need from the buffer using `sscanf()` (or a pair of pointers)

One way to approach this is to separate everything up to the first digit into `name` and then convert the remaining number of `age`. Then you simply remove any trailing spaces from `name` by overwriting the *whtiespace* character with the *nul-terminating* character to trim any trailing whitespace from `name`. You can use `strlen()` to get the length of all characters in `name` and then use a pointer to the last character and work backwards toward the beginning removing whitespace until the first non-whitespace character is found.

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAXC 1024       /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define MAXNM  64

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    
    char buf[MAXC];     /* buffer to hold each line */
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;
    
    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }
    
    while (fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) {             /* read each line of input */
        char name[MAXNM];                       /* name */
        int age;                                /* age */
        /* parse contents of buf into name and age -- VALIDATE */
        if (sscanf (buf, "%63[^0-9]%d", name, &age) == 2) {
            size_t len = strlen(name);          /* get length of name */
            char *p = name + len - 1;           /* pointer to last char in name */
            
            while (p > name && isspace(*p))     /* while char is whitespace */
                *p-- = 0;                       /* overwrite with nul-terminating char */
            
            printf ("name: '%s'  age: %d\n", name, age);
        }
    }
    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);       /* close file if not stdin */
}
```

(**note:** there is nothing special about a "buffer". It is just a character array (or `unsigned char` or `uint8_t`) sufficiently large to hold the entirety of what it is you need to temporarily store -- ***don't skimp on buffer size***. You can adjust downward as needed if on a micro-controller with limited memory)

Also do not **hardcode filenames** or **numbers** (called *Magic Numbers*) unless there is no alternative --- as above when providing the field-width modifier to the `%[^0-9]` conversion specifier. Otherwise, if you need a constant `#define` one or use a global `enum` if you have multiple constants to define.

**Example Use/Output**

With your original example in `dat/name_age.txt` you would have:

```
$ ./bin/name_age dat/name_age.txt
name: 'Jenny'  age: 16
name: 'Amy'  age: 24
```

or in the case of the example with `"Minnie Mouse       92"`:

```
$ ./bin/name_age <dat/name_age2.txt
name: 'Jenny'  age: 16
name: 'Minnie Mouse'  age: 92
```

Look things over and let me know if you have questions.